# How To display text when we click button

Tags: ajax

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script>
       function loadXMLDoc()
       {
          Welcome To Ajax
       }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
      <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

How to display text when we click button. How to display text when we click button?

Comment: the question is confusing, whether you need help reading xml doc or displaying text on the page?

Comment: when we click button it should display welcome to ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function loadXMLDoc()
   {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<h2>Welcome To Ajax</h2>"
   }
```